# Strange error when installing sonarqube 4.3

Tags: jdbc, sonarqube

Im trying to install sonarQube and this is the steps I have taken:

- Downloaded sonarqube version 4.3
- Unpacked sonarqube-4.3.zip to C:\sonarqube
- Start sonarqube by running: C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
- Server running
- Testet access to server on `http://localhost:9000`
- Comment out the following line in C:\sonarqube\conf\sonar.properties
- `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar`
- Edit the following lines in C:\sonarqube\conf\sonar.properties
- sonar.jdbc.username=sonar to sonar.jdbc.username=username
- sonar.jdbc.password=sonar to sonar.jdbc.password=password
- #sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host/XE to sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/db
- Download ojdbc6.jar
- Copy ojdbc6.jar to C:\sonarqube\extensions\jdbc-driver\oracle\
- Stop server
- Start server
- Starting server fails

I get this in the log:

Any help or pointers appreciated

```
2014.06.03 11:13:55 INFO  [o.s.a.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2014.06.03 11:13:56 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2014.06.03 11:13:56 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardService]  Starting service Tomcat
2014.06.03 11:13:56 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardEngine]  Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014.06.03 11:13:57 INFO  [o.a.c.s.ContextConfig]  No global web.xml found
2014.06.03 11:13:59 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.3 / 05cc0b97a0e8064857d02c03a8086695e154e2ba
2014.06.03 11:13:59 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformServletContextListener]  Fail to start server
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.server.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:39) ~[EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:91) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:71) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:53) ~[PlatformServletContextListener.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because the property "sonar.jdbc.url" is not defined or is commented-out in your sonar.properties file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply... a bit of vacation kicked in. This is how my config file looks:

https://gist.github.com/localgod/36e4725d8cdeddd0531b

Comment: Euh and so that's what I was saying : the property sonar.jdbc.url is not defined ? I'm expecting to see : "sonar.jdbc.url=oracle:thin:ora-cctoolt:1521/cctoolt" and not "sonar.jdbc:oracle:thin:ora-cctoolt:1521/cctoolt"

Comment: Changing it to `sonar.jdbc.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@ora-cctoolt:1521/cctoolt` did the trick. Thank you.